# Telegram new user creations sends confirmation code to... Telegram?

Tags: telegram

I am trying to create a Telegram account on my Android phone. I enter my country and my *brand new* phone number, then click next. Now it says "we have sent you a message **in telegram** with the code" which sounds bizarre. I don't think you can receive a message during the setup phase, and what would be the point security wise? So I don't understand what they could possibly mean by this. I have received no message whatsoever on my Telegram. This must mean it's impossible for anyone to join Telegram.

Comment: There's a possibility that it's actually a reused number by the cell provider. However, I don't know any solutions because I didn't have any issues when I registered Telegram on my Android months ago.

Comment: Maybe it is aware I am using the same device? And why should that matter?

Comment: I meant, the phone number probably has been used for Telegram account registration *by the previous owner of the phone number*. If that's the case, then related on WebApps.SE: [Use previously registered telephone number in Telegram](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/93423/79784), in which, I'm afraid it might be difficult since the previous owner has to change phone number inside their Telegram. Security-wise, this is likely to prevent account hijacking.

Comment: @AndrewT I know what you meant, and I was offering a separate thought. Thank you for the link though.